# Choose version of Office running on a computer

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I had a **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016** installation on a Windows 10 PC. I later installed a **Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus 2016** on the same PC, using a license from the company I work for.

When I open say Excel, I see the **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016** version, as I can't see the new features specific to the 365 version, so I guess that although I can see both installations in *Add and Remove programs*, I can only use the first installation (or license?).

Is there a way to switch which version of Office I run? Could I uninstall the Professional Plus 2016 instalation and transfer the licence to another PC? how?

Thanks

Comment: Which features exactly are unique to Office 365?  You can’t have two versions of Office that are the same build (i.e the current version aka 2016) on a system

Comment: For example, the option "Insert Icon" in Powerpoint on 365. it is available in the O365 version but not in the Professional Plus. In "add and remove programs" I can see both versions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like completely uninstalling Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 lets the other version show up. I can see now the O365 specific options.